# New data insertion, resulting in duplicate paging data

Tags: java

Problem Description:
The page-by-page query function searches in the reverse order based on the ID. When the first query is made, the amount of data is 20, and the first page displays data A1-A10.
A new record is inserted before clicking the next page. When you click the next page, A10 appears on the second page, causing the data to appear repeatedly.

Is there a solution to this problem?

My current solution is to carry a unique ID when the data is passed to the front end. The front end traverses the array to have an ID. If it does, it will not be displayed.

Comment: But for the mobile phone side, sliding the page, there is duplicate data, the experience is very unfriendly!

Comment: Now, if you come back to the first page, do you want to see the new data or keep showing an outdated list ? For me, the behavior you have is correct and less problematic. EDIT: this is exactly the behavior you found on SO for example!

Comment: Go back to the home page and need to refresh. @Vasco His plan can solve my problem

Comment: @AxelH，SO， What do you mean?

Comment: So if you come from the second page and go back to the first page, you could miss some values since you didn't show it in the second page. (SO = StackOverflow, sorry ^^)

Comment: @AxelH，Going back to the first page, the list is refreshed. The current problem is to avoid duplicate records in the already displayed data. Because the APP side, there is no paging button, it is pulled down on the page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming SQL query,you could include condition of id < theLastDisplayedRecordId in the where clause of your select query. For the first page this will be 0.